# What does "these" refer to in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it refer to "See's Candies and Coca-Cola's stocks"?

> It's not the not selling that makes these so good, it's that discipline to buy things only when he really, really likes them," Lowenstein says.

Source: [Warren Buffett's winning investing strategy can be applied to any purchase you make](http://www.cnbc.com/2017/05/10/warren-buffetts-investment-strategy-can-help-you-build-wealth.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't be sure, but after reading the article it seems like it's a mistake in the quote. The quote is seemingly talking about Buffett's ability to pick good investments, but it doesn't make sense with the word *these*. What I believe the quote was supposed to be:

> "It's not the not selling that makes **him** so good, it's that discipline to buy things only when he really, really likes them," Lowenstein says.

Corrected, it's saying that what makes Buffett good is not sticking with his investments, but his self-control when it comes to choosing what to invest in.

Comment: **these** might refer back to "worthwhile investments" at the top of the article.

Comment: That's what I thought too at first, but the second half of the statement doesn't make sense if that's the case though. The first half suggests the fact the stocks had not been sold as the reason they're good, but then starts talking about Buffett's discipline in the same sentence. I just cannot find a logical way to parse it with the *these* referring to the investments.